# Concatenating specific STRING

Tags: oracle

Please help me, i dont know how to do this
The records I have are like this: 
as can be seen in column d I wish the L5TX value is concatenated to the sequence 2 and 3 in the same column.

```
   A               B          C       D        E             F
```

|025640060503031 | 16042010 | 13:41:58 |1L1TX | AVENGER |STRING 1 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |3..   | AVENGER |STRING 3 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |2..   | AVENGER |STRING 2 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |1L5TX | AVENGER |STRING 1 cesarin

I wanted the output to be something like:

```
   A               B          C       D        E             F
```

|025640060503031 | 16042010 | 13:41:58 |1L1TX | AVENGER |STRING 1 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |3L5TX | AVENGER |STRING 3 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |2L5TX | AVENGER |STRING 2 cesarin
|667006050303120 | 17042010 | 12:18:57 |1L5TX | AVENGER |STRING 1 cesarin

Comment: Your question is not clear: `select * from <table>` ?

Comment: I need to select and concatenate specific strings from each record of column A

Comment: Your example of output doesn't reflect it. Fix your question please!

Comment: I want to insert or concatenate the string L5TX in the column D when the sequence are 2 and 3 if the  number of column A is the same

Comment: Since you can't explain properly what is it exactly you're trying to do - I'm voting to close this question. Next time, please take the time to properly explain the problem, provide a clear example, maybe ask someone else to go over it and see that they can understand what you're writing. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry I'm a student and I have no certain knowledge but I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This query gives desired output:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6435e/1)

```
select a, b, c, rn||substr(fv, 2) d, e, f 
  from (
    select a, b, c, d, e, f, 
        row_number() over (partition by a order by f) rn,
        first_value(d) over (partition by a order by f) fv
    from test)
```

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to change ordering to `order by d`, and concatenate first letter from column `d` instead `rn`, hard to say for given examples. Documentation for function [first_value()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642).

Comment: The accompanying documentation is quite illustrative thanks for your time.

Comment: hello, good morning, do you know you know how I convert a char value at varchar2 ? in oracle

Comment: Probably you need [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm#i1269136), for instance `cast(char_value as varchar2(10))`.

Comment: thanks a lot, was a great help